# Drag and drop from JList / JTable with Object

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jlist

I have some problems with Drag and Drop with Java.

It's pretty simple I think, I just want to allow a Drag drag and drop custom object from a JList to another.

I've read lot of resources about that and now I have this code :

```
listPlantation = new JList();
plantationList = Plantation.plantations;
DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
Iterator<Plantation> it = plantationList.iterator(); 
// Here I instance my ListModel with my custom Element
while(it.hasNext())
{
    Plantation obj = it.next();
    if(obj !=null)
    {
        dlm.addElement(obj);
    }
}
// Yeah of course I want Drag Enable :) 
listPlantation.setDragEnabled(true);
// Ok let's create my Transferhandler
listPlantation.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler() {

    @Override
    protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {

        JList list =  (JList) c;
        Object vin  = list.getSelectedValue();
        if(vin instanceof VinAbstract)
        {
            System.out.println(vin);
            // I  created my Own transferable object for my custom object 
            return new TransferableVinAbstract((VinAbstract) vin);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
        return COPY; // COPY MOVE COPY_OR_MOVE same problem :)
    }
});
listPlantation.setModel(dlm);
```

If I comment the SetTransferHandler part, it's working , but I only have the String representation of my object.

And when SetTransferHandler part is "On", when I drag my object, in createTransferable >> System.out.println(vin) print me somethings good.

The weirdest things is that I use more or less the same code for a JTree and it's working, but it's also doesn't work with JTable....

Thanks for your reflexion anyway !

Comment: Maybe [this tutorial](http://www.straub.as/java/clip-dnd/dnd.html) could be helpful. It was so for me, I had a similiar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to code a custom renderer to handle your object.

Comment: Thanks Adeel for your answer. I'll try to make a custom renderer and post feedback. (but I still  not understand why I would have to do that for JList but not for a JTree #ItsMistery)